# React components not visible when hosted at github pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-pages

I made a SignUp page using React and tried to host it using GitHub Pages.

It is being hosted at- https://karan-t.github.io/signuppage/
and the repo used is https://github.com/karan-t/signuppage/

While running the app locally using VSCode the form shows up normally but when hosted on GHPages the form is hidden(Can see the elements using console). Not sure why this is happening :/

Comment: If you just published it, you might wanna wait a couple of minutes. It takes a little bit of time to process your repo

Comment: Checking now the page has just died... any other fix?